# Using Rank or OVER() to create 1 or zero column SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

This is what my result data looks like at the moment.  Below is a sample of my data.

```
Cust_Nr    Date        FilmName                                                         
    157649306   20150430    Gladiator                                                       
    158470722   20150504    Gladiator                               
    158467945   20150504    Out Of The Furnace                                              
    158470531   20150504    FilmA                                                           
    157649306   20150510    Gladiator                                                       
    158470722   20150515    Gladiator
```

as we can see in the table, customer number :`157649306`  has watched gladiator twice.

How can I create a column like this:

```
Cust_Nr    Date        FilmName                     Watched Gladiator                                   
    157649306   20150430    Gladiator                        1                              
    158470722   20150504    Gladiator                           1   
    158467945   20150504    Out Of The Furnace               0                              
    158470531   20150504    FilmA                            0                              
    157649306   20150510    Gladiator                        0-- Put zero.  Already 1 above

    158470722   20150515    Gladiator                        0 -- We put zero here. The person as already watched it. We put 1 at the top already!
```

The customer numbers,`157649306`  or  `158470722` has watched Gladiator more than once. We only put 1(one) at the first row detection and in the subsequent rows we put zero in the watched Gladiator column.

How can I create such a column?

I tried a variation of `Watched_Gladiator=CASE WHEN Filmnamne LIKE '%Gladiator%' THEN  1  END OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_Nr)`

It did not work.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30352021/428757.

Comment: Ironically a duplicate of op's own question. I knew I had seen it yesterday

Comment: @ChristianBarron - I take it that it's a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30330397/428757